# Git subtree push results in a long object count. How to avoid this?

Tags: git, git-subtree

I added a subtree to my project like this:

```
git subtree add --prefix sites/all/modules \
git@github-ucbdrupal.com:ucbdrupal/migrate_hrweb.git master --squash
```

I set up these remotes:

```
$ git remote -v
migrate-hrweb-github    git@github-ucbdrupal.com:ucbdrupal/migrate_hrweb.git (fetch)
migrate-hrweb-github    git@github-ucbdrupal.com:ucbdrupal/migrate_hrweb.git (push)
origin  ssh://codeserver.dev.76fc8622-a639-4e1e-873e-    963cf71fd555@codeserver.dev.76fc8622-a639-4e1e-873e-963cf71fd555.drush.in:2222/~/repository.git (fetch)
origin ssh://codeserver.dev.76fc8622-a639-4e1e-873e-963cf71fd555@codeserver.dev.76fc8622-    a639-4e1e-873e-963cf71fd555.drush.in:2222/~/repository.git (push)
```

Git status shows no changes.

On the master branch I edit the README.md in the subtree directory.

I commit:

```
[bwood@ucbmbp hrweb-ob-js]$ git commit -am  "Test edit #4 of hrweb_migrate"
[master 6f4b9c1] Test edit #4 of hrweb_migrate
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

I attempt to push this to the migrate-hrweb-github remote:

```
$ git subtree push -P sites/all/modules/migrate_hrweb migrate-hrweb-github master      
using:  migrate-hrweb-github master
```

Now I have to wait for this long count of objects to complete (5 min).  The master project is a large Drupal installation.  I think every object is being counted/filtered:

```
1022/  16200 (1022)  [this updates for a while...]
```

Finally I get:

```
Counting objects: 8, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 559 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github-ucbdrupal.com:ucbdrupal/migrate_hrweb.git   a9c0af1..a6db986  a6db986c0472dbafbd6861f75711a7c509374125 ->   master
```

How can I avoid this long wait on the object count with every commit?  (I'm guessing the answer might be related to 'git subtree split'...?)